# How do I define a function in powershell and call it automatically in the same script? it appears to pend on an enter stroke

Tags: powershell-2.0

I am attempting to automate some free disk space reports and I found this great block of code that does exactly what I need. It's basically a report for getting disk space results via powershell functions and outputting HTML to email

[Code here] (https://sqlpowershell.wordpress.com/2013/10/01/powershell-script-to-monitor-disk-space-of-a-group-of-servers-html-formatted-email-output/)

The issue is that I can't seem to use the function in the same script that I am defining it in. At the bottom I'll use:

```
get-diskspacereport -computerlist list.txt -to email@email -from     email@email.com -SMTPemail smtpaddress
```

If I copy/paste the original code then manually use the function everything works great, but I need to get it all in one so I can automated via task scheduler and a .bat script to call it. If I copy paste it with the command call at the bottom, it's basically waiting for me to press enter to run.

Comment: What error do you get? 
I've tested and it's working here. Make sure you declare the function before calling it.

Comment: It's not really an error, more like just not working. If I copy/paste the original script from the link, then append the code that I typed out on the bottom there, it never actually runs the report. If I copy paste the entire thing into powershell it basically defines the function, then populates the command to call it but never actually runs it. If I press enter it works. I really just want the entire thing in a .ps1 file so I can automate it.

Comment: tried to specify the full path of list.txt ??